# Can I be sure of order of IO actions in this example?

Tags: haskell, io, lazy-evaluation

At the moment, I have this code in and around `main`:

```
import Control.Monad
import Control.Applicative

binSearch :: Ord a => [a] -> a -> Maybe Int

main = do
    xs <- lines <$> readFile "Cars1.txt"
    x <- getLine <* putStr "Registration: "  -- Right?
    putStrLn $ case binSearch xs x of
                    Just n -> "Found at position " ++ show n
                    Nothing -> "Not found"
```

My hope is for “Registration: ” to be printed, then for the program to wait for the input to `x`. Does what I've written imply that that will be the case? Do I need the `<*`, or will putting the `putStr` expression on the line above make things work as well?

PS: I know I have to convert `binSearch` to work with arrays rather than lists (otherwise it's probably not worth doing a binary search), but that's a problem for another day.

Comment: The only place laziness comes into play here is `readFile`, which is kind of a sneaky function -- the file will be read incrementally as `xs` is demanded.  Everything else -- and in general, all actions in the `IO` monad (except `readFile`, `getContents`, which are explicitly written to be lazy) will execute in order as you would expect from an imperative language.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The line

```
x <- getLine <* putStr "Registration: "
```

orders the IO actions left-to-right: first a line is taken as input, then the message is printed, and finally variable `x` is bound to the result of `getLine`.

> Do I need the <*, or will putting the putStr expression on the line
>   above make things work as well?

If you want the message to precede the input, you have to put the `putStr` on the line above, as follows:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    xs <- lines <$> readFile "Cars1.txt"
    putStr "Registration: "
    x <- getLine
    putStrLn $ case binSearch xs x of
                    Just n  -> "Found at position " ++ show n
                    Nothing -> "Not found"
```

Alternatively,

```
    x <- putStr "Registration: " *> getLine
```

or

```
    x <- putStr "Registration: " >> getLine
```

would work, but they are less readable.

Finally, since you added the *lazy-evaluation* tag, let me add that your question is actually not about laziness, but about how the operator `<*` is defined, and in particular about the order in which it sequences the IO actions.

Comment: Yeah I boggled at `<*` a bit, I would find a separate line easier to read.

Comment: So order of statements does matter? I remember doing a similar thing before, and it just acted randomly.

Comment: @JamesWood Yes, all the Applicative operators `<$>,<*>,<*,...`  sequence IO actions left-to-right. The same holds for `liftM,liftM2,...`. Actions inside a `do` also follow this order. The only operators I can recall sequencing actions right-to-left are `<<` and `=<<`, which are the `flip`ped variants of `>>,>>=`.